# How to keep four decimal place in the axis of pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

Here is what I've got:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
x       y
1.3325  1535.5
1.3335  1537.82
1.3349  1540.92
1.3362  1543.62
1.3375  1546
}{\datatable}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/.cd,
precision=5,
/tikz/.cd
}
]
\addplot+[] table [] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To get `1.3320` and `1.3330` instead of `1.332` and `1.333`, you can use `precision=4,  fixed zerofill`.

Comment: It is not easy to know what you mean by "keep"!?

Comment: I would like to see `1.3325` and `1.3335` instead of `1.332` and `1.333`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `xtick=data`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
x       y
1.3325  1535.5
1.3335  1537.82
1.3349  1540.92
1.3362  1543.62
1.3375  1546
}{\datatable}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick=data,
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/.cd,
precision=5,
/tikz/.cd
}
]
\addplot+[] table [] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For tick  label style is sufficient to define it by  `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/precision=4}`. Happy new year!